# Web App Running on Localhost using IIS Express Development Certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, server, iis-express, self-signed-certificate

So we have some software that when installed runs a web app on iis at localhost on the users machine..

In order to use ssl we provide the user with a self signed certificate.. which results in an  error like this when opened on chrome on the users machine..

I'm assuming this is because we are using a self signed certificate..

[image]

Now I noticed if I set the sites certificate to IIS Express Development Certificate the error went away.. and the site loaded normally on chrome..
[image]

So what I'm wondering is if I can install the software that runs the web app on the users machine. THEN can I programmatically set the web sites certificate to IIS's "IIS Express Development Certificate"?

Is this ok to do?

Answer (score 0):

It to OK to share a self-signed certificate with your customers, but that's really not the best practice. For example, if the machine is compromised and the self-signed certificate is replaced by another one generated by the hacker, the customer usually won't notice the difference but the hacker can gain more access (and perform more damage).

Instead, allow your customers to use their own certificates and that's quite common in real world, as many customers have their own AD and CA configured already. They can issue their own certificates for clients/servers.

If you insist using self-signed certificates, ask your customers to trust such manually, for Edge/Chrome,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate

Firefox needs another procedure.

> IIS Express Development Certificate should trigger the same warning by default, but this specific customer might have already trusted it on this machine. However, you cannot assume such applies to all your customer machines.